# My issue related with execution time and database functionality

Tags: php, mysql, database, memcached, execution-time

I have a big issue makes me in bad mood.

My issue related with execution time and database functionality.

When i retrieve a 4000 users from db, And for each users make some functions as update his data, delete or add new data in anther table which related with this user, This process take long time more than 10 mins, And sometimes the script page is down before its ending.

Some people suggest to optimize the queries, I think this the minimal queries i can request to do what i want for my proper cause.

Else people suggest to use memcached technique, But i wonder is this technique is useful for my issue, Most of queries must make change in database as update, insert or delete. In addition this script is run by cronjobs.

---

### Note: I use mysql db extension.

Is there any solutions for this issue ?? As using mysqli or PDO ?? Is that make any maintaining difference ? Or anything else ?

Something else please, If you have any recommendation about execution time and db functionality, Please comment it.

Thank you for attention.

Comment: Post any code, any PHP code or SQL queries, let us see how optimized it is.

Comment: Database server would also be helpful - even the table types, with MySQL, InnoDB tables are slightly better (performance wise) than MyISAM tables when it comes to write operations but slightly worse at read. Prepared statements might also help ... so many variables, so little info.

Comment: There aren't very many valid use cases for performing CRUD operations on 4000 users while in the web browser. Instead, you should look at (if possible) writing a script as a CRON JOB that will run in the background and perform your operations without the timeout limitations in browser requests.

Comment: I'd be curious how big the database is, which type of table they are (usually InnoDB, or the older MyIsam), and how much memory has been given for the database to ue to store the data in memory. MySql can very easily be left at a default 8mb, which won't fit many records at all.